# reading scalar value data from a stored proc and displaying in view of MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am passing a variable to a stored proc and I am trying retrieve the data returned by the stored proc and passing it to the view through ViewBag but I am not getting the value I am expecting to get. I am getting `` System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult`1[System.String] ``. I am using Entity Framework to map my objects.

This is in my controller:

```
string id = collection.Get(0);
var sp = db.sproc_pallet_test(id).ToList();
ViewBag.name = sp;
```

This is code in my view

[image: IMG2]

Comment: paste your code in your question please

Comment: @NPE I just did

Comment: What is `db`? Your DbContext? `sproc_pallet_test` is where you call your procedure? If so, add the call of your stored procedure call inside the post.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer. I needed append .Single() to get the value.

```
   var sp = db.sproc_pallet_test(id).Single();
```

Answer (score 0):

``` System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult``1[System.String] ``` Having this as the output it looks like you are printing the ObjectResult directly without the `.ToList()`

The `sp` from your code snippet will be the class path of the list object

If `db.sproc_pallet_test(id)` is expected to return a single string, use `db.sproc_pallet_test(id).FirstOrDefault()` instead.